# mysql could not recieve table from Citespace

Tags: sql

I created was database through commands (see lower)

```
Started Citespace, clicked DATA - IMPORT/EXPORT
Citespace-Built-in-database
Database-Connect to mySQL
Input directory - choosed directory with WOS files
Project - import data (WOS)​
```

Now check:

```
click Count records
Recieved:
projects  0
articles    0
authors  18020
refs   144499
keywords  64260
phrases    0
institutions  11695
verbs
```

so tables

```
- articles
- bursts
- clusters
- phrases
- verbs
```

are empty 
and system see no projects

CAN YOU help me to understand what i do wrong?

=== database schema

```
CREATE DATABASE wos;
USE wos;
CREATE TABLE articles
(
    id int,
    uid VARCHAR(100),
    project VARCHAR(100),
    author VARCHAR(100),
    title VARCHAR(100),
    abstract VARCHAR(1500),
    source VARCHAR(200),
    j9 VARCHAR(100),
    volume VARCHAR(100),
    issue VARCHAR(100),
    bp VARCHAR(100),
    ep VARCHAR(100),
    page VARCHAR(100),
    dt VARCHAR(100),
    doi VARCHAR(100),
    year int,
    month int,
    date int,
    citations int,
    editor VARCHAR(100),
    tagged boolean
);
/*  TABLE articles 
id(int), uid, project, author, title, abstract, source, j9, volume, issue, bp, ep, page, dt, doi, year(int),
month(int), date(int), citations(int), editor, tagged(boolean)
*/
CREATE TABLE authors
(
id int,
lastname VARCHAR(100),
firstname VARCHAR(100),
initials VARCHAR(100),
project VARCHAR(100),
uid VARCHAR(100),
pos VARCHAR(100)
);
/*  TABLE authors
id(int), lastname, firstname, initials, project, uid, pos */
CREATE TABLE refs
(
id int,
bibcode VARCHAR(100),
ref VARCHAR(100),
doi VARCHAR(100),
author VARCHAR(100),
year VARCHAR(100),
source VARCHAR(100),
volume VARCHAR(100),
page VARCHAR(100),
citer_uid VARCHAR(100),
project VARCHAR(100)
);
/*   TABLE refs
id(int), bibcode, ref, doi, author, year, source, volume, page, citer_uid, project */
CREATE TABLE keywords
(
id int,
keyword VARCHAR(100),
uid VARCHAR(100),
year VARCHAR(100),
project VARCHAR(100),
type VARCHAR(100)
);
/* TABLE keywords
id(int), keyword, uid, year, project, type */
CREATE TABLE phrases
(
id int,
phrase VARCHAR(100),
isTitlePhrase boolean,
project VARCHAR(100),
uid VARCHAR(100),
year int, 
month int, 
date int, 
freq int
);
/*  TABLE phrases
id(int), phrase, isTitlePhrase(booelan), project, uid, year(int), month(int), date(int), freq(int)  */
CREATE TABLE verbs
(
id int,
project VARCHAR(100),
uid VARCHAR(100),
verb VARCHAR(100),
freq VARCHAR(100)
);
/*  TABLE verbs
id(int), project, uid, verb, freq  */
CREATE TABLE bursts
(
id int,
project VARCHAR(100),
term VARCHAR(100),
weight  double,
start int,
end int
);
/* TABLE bursts
id(int), project, term, weight(double), start(int), end(int) */
CREATE TABLE institutions
(
id int,
name VARCHAR(100),
country VARCHAR(100),
uid VARCHAR(100),
year int,
project VARCHAR(100)
);
/* TABLE institutions
id(int), name, country, uid, year(int), project */
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be is that you created data schema manually. You can erase wos database and just use CiteSpace. It creates dataschema automatically. Hope it will be OK.